# How to know the exact node size in other programming languages?

Tags: tikz-pgf, programming

I need to draw some force-directed graph diagrams like this: [Force-directed graph drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing)

I only know some simple Tikz drawing, so I want to do most of the calculation in C# and generate TeX sources.

But I need extra information. I have various texts and formulas on nodes. I need to know the exactly node sizes in C# before TeX takes part.

So I should know either how TeX calculates the size of a node and reproduce that in C#, or let TeX calculate them and return them to C#.

I think both are big problems for me. I need some advice.

Comment: By size you mean width and height, should the nodes box been drawn? // Why can‘t you use the force library from tikz https://tikz.dev/gd-force ?

Comment: @MS-SPO Yes, I mean width and height. The nodes have rectanglular boxes drawn. My graph has some special rules and constraints of forces which I don't know if gd-force support them all. Additionally, I already have the C# code and want to produce multiple versions of graphics like on-screen animation version, SVG version and TeX version (not necessarily be exactly the same look. So I just need nodes' width and height, not considering their minor differences among versions). I want to keep the code relatively independent.

Comment: Some ideas: generate the node with TikZ, put it in a box, use `\widthof` and `\heightof` on the box and print that to a text file, then read that text file in C#. Or: generate all the nodes with TikZ, convert to SVG, parse the SVG with C# to extract sizes.

Comment: @Marijn Thanks a lot. I think the first method is good for me. I'll try it.